# apply arrow function as object property in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript2.0, ecmascript-2017

I have following code and wondering if I can apply as arrow function on line `data({value}: {value: string}) {return func(value); },`

```
function func(value: string){
    return `${value} has been formated`
}
const rowData = {
  height: 20,
  data({value}: {value: string}) {
    return func(value);
  },
  width: 130,
};

console.log(rowData.data({value:'aaaa'})) //aaaa has been formated
```

I have try  `data({value}: {value: string}) => func(value),` but it does not seem to work

Comment: `data: (...) => ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```js
const rowData = {
  // ...
  data: ({value}: {value: string}) => func(value),
  // ...
};
```

There's not a significant advantage to this other than syntax, given you're not accessing `this` from the `rowData` object. The function will also be anonymous, which makes it unnamed in stack traces.